# Changing the Background color of a single element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a timetable for school. I have about 50 buttons of the same class but with different id´s. is it possible to change the color of a specific Button with a specific id with a function in js?
`<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openPopup1()" id="output1"><strong>+</strong></button> <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openPopup2()" id="output2"><strong>+</strong></button>`

These are two of the Buttons as an Example

i had no ideas how to do it and found nothing after research so i hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with document.getElementById("output1").style.backgroundColor="red"?  Essentially sets an inline style on the button.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill and not what you are looking for. But if you pass **this** to your onclick function, you can reference that button in the function.

In my example, I add a class of active to whatever button was clicked and remove active from any other clicked buttons.

```js
function deactiveBtns(){
  let activeBTNs = document.querySelectorAll(".btn.active");
  activeBTNs.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

function openPopup1(el){
 deactiveBtns();
 el.classList.toggle("active");
}

function openPopup2(el){
 deactiveBtns();
  el.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.btn.active{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openPopup1(this)" id="output1"><strong>+</strong></button> <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openPopup2(this)" id="output2"><strong>+</strong></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of a button with JS by accessing the element by Id and setting the style attribute appropriately.

```
document.getElementById("headerStore").setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

You can do it when the page is loaded, or trigger it with the click of a button. You can also reference specific items by ID with CSS as well.

Hopefully this helps!